# How do I hide the extra rows in javafx tableview?

Tags: javafx, javafx-8

I have constructed my tableview using SceneBuilder.

I am trying to add different context menus for the table and rows as described [here](http://www.marshall.edu/genomicjava/2013/12/30/javafx-tableviews-with-contextmenus/).

My table has 2 rows with actual data. By default, the extra space gets filled with a bunch of empty rows. Is there a way to disable the addition of the empty rows?

My goal is to display the row specific context menus when I click on the rows and the tableview-level context menu in the rest of the table.

For now, I have disabled the row-level context menu by -

```
// only display context menu for non-null items:
row.contextMenuProperty().bind(
  Bindings.when(Bindings.isNotNull(row.itemProperty()))
  .then(rowMenu)
  .otherwise((ContextMenu)null));
```

Comment: Showing some code would help to get more attraction. Haiya...(it's ninja thing)

Comment: Thanks... provided some more context...

Comment: This question has nothing to do with the context menu, right?

Comment: Thanks, that is useful and partially solves my problem. How do I display the tableview-level context menu for the blank rows?